# Forge Viewer - Having markups in the same size for each plan

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

version 7.21.0

I'm trying to make all markups in the same size for each plan (2D - dwg)

```
markupsExtension.setStyle('stroke-width': 0.3);
```

for a small plan 0.3 is a really thick line. and for a big plan its really thin. is there a way to get a 'pixel to unit' value or the plan size ? so i can set the same line width to each one.

this is the object settings that i'm using to uploading the file to forge

Thank,
Tal :)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the page dimensions from the Forge model metadata:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the quick response, it looks like each plan has the same size :/ https://imgur.com/4YmW9J6